# Getting actual value of an array in loop

Tags: php, arrays

I am working on the following demo. Why am I getting only the index number of array instead of actual value?

```
<?php

$input = array("Neo", "Morpheus", "Trinity", "Cypher", "Tank");
$rand_keys = array_rand($input, 2);

foreach($rand_keys as $value) {
    print $value;
}


$length = count($rand_keys);
for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
    print $rand_keys[$i];
}

?>
```

Output:

```
0202
```

Comment: `print $rand_keys[$i];` -> print `$input[$rand_keys[$i]];`? Use the keys for your array with the data. And don't access the keys again in the for loop

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right now you basically do this:

```
$input = array("Neo", "Morpheus", "Trinity", "Cypher", "Tank");
$rand_keys = array_rand($input, 2); //Array ( [0] => Random Key 1 [1] => Random Key 2 )
```

Foreach loop:

```
foreach($rand_keys as $value) {
  print $value;
}
```

```
╔═══════════════╦══════════════╗
║ Iteration Nr. ║    $value    ║
╠═══════════════╬══════════════╣
║ 1             ║ Random Key 1 ║
║ 2             ║ Random Key 2 ║
╚═══════════════╩══════════════╝
```

For loop:

```
$length = count($rand_keys);
for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
  print $rand_keys[$i];
}
```

```
╔═══════════════╦════╦════════════════╦═════════╗
║ Iteration Nr. ║ $i ║ $rand_keys[$i] ║ $length ║
╠═══════════════╬════╬════════════════╬═════════╣
║ 1             ║ 0  ║ Random Key 1   ║ 2       ║
║ 2             ║ 1  ║ Random Key 2   ║ 2       ║
╚═══════════════╩════╩════════════════╩═════════╝
```

---

So `array_rand()` just returns random keys. Use that returned keys to access elements in your input array:

```
$input = array("Neo", "Morpheus", "Trinity", "Cypher", "Tank");
$rand_keys = array_rand($input, 2);

foreach($rand_keys as $key) {
    echo $input[$key];
}
```

Comment: @Rizier123 wow thanks for the edit, you're probably bored lol :D, no good questions posted in a while

Comment: You're welcome :) Just tried to improve your answer a bit.